# how to get value of an xml element not directly under root

Tags: python

I am trying to parse an xml and get the value of `dir_path` as below,however I dont seem to get the desired output,whats wrong here and how to fix it?

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <data>
    <software>
      <name>xyz</name>
      <role>xyz</role>
      <future>unknown</future> 
    </software>
    <software>
      <name>abc</name>
      <role>abc</role>
      <future>clear</future>
      <dir_path cmm_root_path_var="COMP_softwareROOT">\\location\software\INR\</dir_path>
      <loadit reduced="true">
        <RW>yes</RW>
        <readonly>R/</readonly>
      </loadit>
      <upload reduced="true">
      </upload>
    </software>
    <software>
      <name>def</name>
      <role>def</role>
      <future>clear</future>
      <dir_path cmm_root_path_var="COMP2_softwareROOT">\\location1\software\INR\</dir_path>
      <loadit reduced="true">
        <RW>yes</RW>
        <readonly>R/</readonly>
      </loadit>
      <upload reduced="true">
      </upload>
    </software>
    </data>
```

CODE:-

```
tree = ET.parse(input.xml)
root = tree.getroot()
dir_path = root.find(".//dir_path")
print dir_path.text
```

OUTPUT:-

```
.\
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
\\location\software\INR\
```

Comment: This actually works just fine for me.. what does `dir_path.attrib` return?

Comment: forgot to add one point..I need to get the dir_path.attrib under the one with name `abc` ,there are multiple dir_path's under different names, updated the input.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('filename.xml')

item = tree.find('software/[name="abc"]/dir_path')
print(item.text if item is not None else None)
```

Comment: need double front slash`//` ,it does print the text but throws an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` ..how do we take care of the `NoneType` case

Comment: You don't need `//`. Actually, you could get the information without any `.` or `/` because they are direct children. If one of the `software` does not have a `name` child, you can test it (see modified xpaths), but if it does not have a `dir_path`, you have to test it before trying to get the `.text`

Comment: See the simplified version that uses a more elaborated XPath expression.